# Social media links in TYPO3 using typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm newbie to TypoScript. I actually don't know how to make link like this:
[image]

By googling, I got some idea on typoscript like this:

```
lib.social = COA
lib.social.special = language
lib.social.special.value = 0,1,2
lib.social.1 = GMENU
lib.social.1{
    wrap = <ul> | </ul>
    noBlur = 1
    expAll = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
        ATagTitle.field = title // nav_title
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
        accessKey = 1
    }
}
lib.social.1.NO{
    XY = [5.w]+4, [5.h]+4
    5 = IMAGE
    5.file = {$global.imagePath}facebook.png || {$global.imagePath)twitter.png || {$global.imagePath)xing.png
    5.offset = 2,2
}
```

I'm sure I got a problem with `lib.social = language` and I also try different things lik directory or browse but it still does not work and I may have some mistakes with the above script which I can't figure out.

In overall, I don't know how to make it work by linking to the external urls using typoscript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most of social networks has their own embedding code so you don't need to create it manually, just can put into the marker the code...

   ```
   lib.social = COA
   lib.social.10 = TEXT
   lib.social.10.value = <fb:like send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
   ```
2. you can also use [www.addthis.com](http://www.addthis.com/) to place many different social buttons
3. If you need to use custom graphics anyway, use common links, each with custom id attribute, then just use CSS to set it's display as `block` set the `width`,`height`, `float` (to make sure the each button is in the sam line, and finally `background-image` with your buttons. Use `sprite` technique for the image for best results (all buttons in one file, then set correct button for link with `background-position`

Answer (score 1):

I see u just want to have some image menu.

1. Create a new page of type `Menu Separator` in your `pagetree`
2. Create a new page for every menu item and use type `Link to External URL` (don't forget to fillin the url in the page properties)
3. Upload your image inside the page properties under `Resources` -> `media`
4. Use the code below to show the menu on your `front-end` (replace `special.value = 2000` with the page ID of your `social` page.

Code: http://shrib.com/gRrK9uGL

(sorry didnt get the code visible here)

Comment: Code update for version 6.2 and typo3 7.0 https://github.com/ionasrobert/Tests/blob/master/newTSTemplate.ts